# Java input/output confusion

Tags: java, parseint

I am writing a program and I need to input a value for index, but the index should be composite, e.g 44GH.
My question is, how to make the program to do not crash when I ask the user to input it and then I want to display it?

I have been looking for answer in the site, but they are only for integer or string type.
If anyone can help, would be really appreciated.

```
         Scanner s input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private ArrayList<Product> productList;

    System.out.println("Enter the product");
    String product = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Input code for your product e.g F7PP");
    String code = s.nextLine();
}
public void deleteProduct(){
   System.out.println("Enter the code of your product that you want to delete ");
    String removed = input.nextLine();
            if (productList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("There are no products for removing");
       }  else {
    String aString = input.next(); 
    productList.remove(aString);
}
}
```

Comment: If you parse a string containing letters as an integer, your code will crash.  There is not way around this.  Can you tell us more about what you plan to do with the input `44GH` ?

Comment: It is for a program that ask the user to input a name of a product, and a code and the code should be something like 44GH. Then the program should ask the user to input a code from the keyboard and the program should delete it.

Comment: it's not really clear what you're trying to do.  Do you mean you just want to ditch the non-numeric part?

Comment: I want the non-numeric and the numeric part together. And I need to delete this "index", which contains both non-numeric and numeric part

Comment: I updated the code

Answer (score 4):

Remove all non digits char before casting to integer:

```
String numbersOnly= aString.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
Integer result = Integer.parseInt(numbersOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to create some RegEx that could solve this problem, and you test if your input matches your RegExp. Here's a good website to test RegExp : [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)

Then, when you know how to extract the Integer part, you parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP wants to print out a string just but correct me if I am wrong. So,

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String aString = input.nextLine(); // FFR55 or something is expected
    System.out.println(aString);
```

Then obviously you can use:

```
    aString.replaceAll();
    Integer.parseInt();
```

To modify the output but from what I gather, the output is expected to be something like FFR55.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the code split the two parts:

```
int numbers = Integer.parseInt(string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
String chars = string.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").toUpperCase();
int char0Index = ((int) chars.charAt(0)) - 65;
int char1Index = ((int) chars.charAt(1)) - 65;
```

This code makes a variable `numbers`, holding the index of the number part of the input string, as well as `char0Index` and `char1Index`, holding the value of the two characters from 0-25.

You can add the two characters, or use the characters for rows and numbers for columns, or whatever you need.